# Understanding the space occupied by an vector instance in C++

Tags: c++, std

I'm trying to understand the amount of bytes occupied by an instance of std::vector. The following code:

```
    vector <int>uno;
    uno.push_back(1);
    uno.push_back(1);
    cout <<"1: "<< sizeof(uno)<<" bytes"<<endl;
    cout << endl;

    vector <bool>unos;
    unos.push_back(true);
    cout <<"2: "<< sizeof(unos)<<" bytes"<<endl;
    cout << endl;
```

gives me this output:

1: 12 bytes

2: 20 bytes

Can someone explain me why the size of the `vector<bool>` has more bytes than the `vector<int>`?. And what is the correct way to measure the size in bytes of an vector instance... by adding the size of every member in the vector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, the `sizeof` operator is *always* evaluated at compile time, so every `vector<T>` will have the same size (unless `vector<T>` is a specialization like `vector<bool>`).

In case you are wondering about the 12 bytes, that is probably the size of 3 pointers, or alternatively, the size of a pointer and an element count and a capacity. The real data is never stored inside the `vector`.

If you want to know how much memory is used total, a good approximation is:

```
sizeof(std::vector<T>) + my_vector.capacity() * sizeof(T)
```

This is only an approximation because it does not take into account book-keeping data on the heap.

Comment: For vector, there should be no need for additional book-keeping on the heap.

Comment: @kot: I'm not sure what you mean. Every heap allocation has *some* invisible book-keeping data specific to the implementation.

Comment: OK, that is true - misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector<bool>` is larger since it is more complicated than `std::vector<int>`. The current C++ standard specifies that the `vector<bool>` data should be bit-packed. This requires some additional bookkeeping, and gives them a slightly different behavior than the normal `std::vector<T>`.

This different behavior of `std::vector<bool>` is very likely to be removed in the upcoming C++0x standard.

Comment: I wish. But so far, the committee has voted to keep it, and there doesn't really seem to be consensus to do anything about it. I think it's here to stay.