# Printing the First Array in a Deque of Structs

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, iterator, deque

I have a Deque that contains this kind of stucts.

```
struct New_Array {                    
    array<array<int,4>,4> mytable;       
    int h;
};
```

In this stuct 2 different arrays may have same value of h.

```
deque<New_Array> Mydeque;
```

I also know how many different h are in the deque(the value of `steps`). And how many stucts are in the deque(`Mydeque.size()`).

**I need to print one array for each h.** Starting from `h=0` till `h=steps` (steps is a known `int` value). **Each array that is going to be printed must be the closer to the end of the deque.**

I tried something like this:

```
void foo(deque<New_Array> Mydeque, int steps)
 for(int i=0; i<steps; i++)
     {
        deque<New_Array>::iterator it;
        it = find(Mydeque.begin(),Mydeque.end(),i);
        PrintBoard(*it); // This if a function where you enter the New_Array struct 
                         // and it prints the array         
     }
}
```

The above gives me : `error C2679: binary '==' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const bool' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Or something like this:

```
void foo(deque<New_Array> Mydeque, int steps)
for(int i=0; i<steps; i++)
     {
        deque<New_Array>::iterator it;
        for(unsigned int j=0;j<Mydeque.size();j++)
            {
            it = find_if(Mydeque.begin(),Mydeque.end(),Mydeque[j].h==i);
            PrintBoard(*it);
            break;
            }           

     }
```

The above gives me: `error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments`

**EDIT**: The `deque` is not sorted. For each `h` an `array` should be printed. This `array` should be the one that is **at this moment** closer to the end of the deque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

```
void Find_Solution_Path(deque<New_Array> Mydeque, int steps)
{
for(int i=0; i<steps+1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=Mydeque.size()-1;j>-1;j--)
        {
            if (Mydeque[j].h==i)
            {
                PrintBoard(Mydeque[j]);
                cout<<endl;
                break;
            }    
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember the last value and skip:

```
assert(!Mydeque.empty());
int old_h = Mydeque[0].h + 1; // make sure it's different!

for (std::size_t i = 0, end != Mydeque.size(); i != end; ++i)
{
    if (Mydeque[i].h == old_h) continue;

    print(Mydeque[i]);
    old_h = Mydeque[i].h;
}
```

Comment: Assuming the deque is not sorted, there is no quicker way than to start from the beginning.

Comment: Only works if the `deque` is sorted, which I see no indication that it is.

Comment: @Kerrek If the values of h in the deque is like this: 0, 5 , 2, 1 ,4 , your code will print only the 1st, and 4th element of the Deque.

Comment: OK, never mind then. I thought the original collection was already sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, note that you declare your `std::array` on the stack, so the storage will also be on the stack. This means that iterating over the structure involves loading a (4*4+1)*int for each comparison. If this is performance-sensitive, I would suggest using `std::vector` since the load will be only of the outer vector pointer and the `h` when only comparing `h`.

```
struct New_Array {                    
    vector<vector<int,4>,4> mytable;
    int h;
};
```

Secondly, if you need to access these tables through their `h` values, or access all the tables with a given `h` at once, make it easier for everyone and store them as vectors in a map, or a sorted vector of vectors:

```
std::map<int,std::vector<New_Array> > rolodex;
rolodex[someNewArray.h].push_back(someNewArray);
```

If you construct this in-order, then the first item in each vector will be the one to print:

```
for(auto it : rolodex) {
    vector<New_Array> tablesForThisH = it->second;
    if(tablesForThisH.begin() != tablesForThisH.end())
       PrintBoard(it->second[0]);
}
```

Since `std:map` stores (and iterates) its keys in ascending (I think) order, this will run over the different `h` values in ascending order. Again it will only need to load the stack-stored struct, which is just the `h` int and the vector header (probably 12 bytes, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421698/understanding-the-space-occupied-by-an-vector-instance-in-c)).

Forgive me if the code is wrong, my stl is a little rusty.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `deque`, and insert all elements into a `map`, using `h` as the key.  Since your set of `h` values seems to be sequential, you can use a `vector` instead, but testing whether an element has already been found will be more difficult.